# Joining two parts together to make a single script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, curl, html

I'm trying to create a script to do the following:
extract the magnet link from a lynx bookmark and then use it as part of a curl command. like this:

```
curl http://my_ip:my_port_number/startdownload/magnet_link
```

I have the following to get the magnet link:

```
lynx -dump -hiddenlinks=listonly lynx_bookmarks.html | grep "magnet" | sed 's/&.*//' | cut -c 7-
```

But I am unsure as to how to glue the two parts together to create a single script.

Can I have some suggestions please?

BTW, I am a total amateur at this and I'm sure that even what have can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

So what you need is to capture the output of one command, and use it in another. The bash $(..) syntax will let you execute a command and capture the output, then you can use that output in another command.

One way is to capture the output in a variable, such as:

```
shortcut=$(lynx -dump -hiddenlinks=listonly lynx_bookmarks.html | grep magnet | sed 's/&.*//' | cut -c 7-)
curl "$shortcut"
```

Or, you can use the output directly:

```
curl $(lynx -dump -hiddenlinks=listonly lynx_bookmarks.html | grep "magnet" | sed 's/&.*//' | cut -c 7-)
```

Which you choose depends on your preference. If you need to use the output of the command more than once then it is a good idea to capture the output in a variable and use it from there.

Answer (score 1):

put the following lines into a script file, such ad mydownload.sh

```
magnet=$(lynx -dump -hiddenlinks=listonly lynx_bookmarks.html | grep "magnet" | sed 's/&.*//' | cut -c 7-)
curl http://my_ip:my_port_number/startdownload/${magnet}
```

save and exit

```
chmod 755 mydownload.sh
./mydownload.sh
```

Comment: Thanks Mel, this is what I was looking for. Thanks go out to everybody else as well, your answers have been very helpful and informative.

Answer (score 0):

```
bash-4.1$ echo $( echo hi )
hi
bash-4.1$
```

So,

```
curl $( ... )
```

Would pass the output of whatever `...` is to `curl` by running whatever those commands are as a subshell. `$()` can also be written with backticks, though those are header to read, and do not nest.

`grep | sed` can probably be replaced with a single call to `awk`.